# Problema complicado

Tags: c++

Como fazer em C++ um programa que imprima o numero do usuário da seguinte forma:

```
5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2
5 4 3
5 4
5
```

Isso está muito complicado para mim.

Comment: coloque seu código, e que número é esse?

Comment: Esse número é só para exemplo, quando o usuário digitar qualquer número, ele tem que ir decrescendo da mesma forma que esse exemplo

Comment: [**Você acha esse seu problema complicado?**](http://geradormemes.com/media/created/7llrv7.jpg) Comece a dar uma olhada nas questões e respostas que temos aqui no site que você vai ver coisa muito mais complicada que a sua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente esse código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void imprimeRecursivo(int numero, int final) {
  if(final <= numero) {
    for (int i = numero; i >= final; i--) {
        cout << i;
    }
    cout << "\n";
    imprimeRecursivo(numero, final + 1);
  }
}

int main()
{ 
  imprimeRecursivo(5, 1);
}
```

E se não for com recursividade:

```
void imprimeComLoop(int numero, int final) {
    for ( int p = final; p <= numero; p++) {
        for (int i = numero; i >= p; i--) {
            cout << i;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu apresentei essa resposta sem saber o contexto ou o real problema que pretende resolver..

Comment: Mas não posso usar recursividade. Apenas usando for, while ou do while, esse é o problema ;/

Comment: Mas é exatamente isso que tem que ser feito

Comment: Isso me parece exercícios de algoritmos na faculdade, tente esclarecer o porquê das suas perguntas, veja quanta gente negativou ela. E esses votos negativos é porque você não apresentou seu código, não explicou o que está fazendo e para quê, assim complica as coisas para quem está tentando entender como te ajudar

Comment: Tudo bem, desculpa. É a minha primeira vez aqui...

Comment: Que isso! Não se sinta oprimido por ninguém, a idéia é fazer o melhor para a comunidade crescer!!